# How to connect to accept money on behalf of others in stripe

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

I am working on an e-commerce IOS app which use `stripe payment gateway` for payment. I am very new in this topic. When I create an account on stripe then I get two keys one `secrete_kye` and another is `publishable_key`.

I can create charge for an account using ruby by following code:

```
Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_TEST_SECRET_KEY']
   source = params[:stripeToken]   
   charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
       :amount => params[:amount],
       :currency => "usd",
       :source => source,
       :description => "First Charge"
   )
```

I have to distribute this `amount` to two accounts. I know how to achieve this, I have to use stripe connect feature and by doing following code I can do so:

```
Stripe.api_key = PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY
  Stripe::Charge.create({    
  :amount => 1000,     
  :currency => "usd",       
  :source => {TOKEN}     
 }, {:stripe_account => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID})
```

But till now I don't know how to get `PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY` and `CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID`.

I already read stripe documentation by previous one week but can't understand how to get those keys for testing purpose.

If anyone give me some direction to use stripe connect and find those keys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) say?

Comment: @meaning-matters  They provided all information I don't find any sequence tutorial to do such things. I read almost all the page of stripe documentation related to stripe connect.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to make charges on connected accounts: directly, as the connected account; or by using the `destination`-parameter, as the platform account.

In your example, you're charging directly.  You're using your Platform Account's permissions to act on behalf of your Connected Account, by passing their accound ID in the `Stripe-Account`-header.

To split funds between the two when making a charge, you pass an `application_fee`-argument in the Create a Charge [1] API Request.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge

With either approach, you'll always use your Platform's API Keys (ie. your API Key == `PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY`).

When you connect to another account, you'll see the Connected Account's account ID returned as part of the response (ie. the connected account == `CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID`).

Got all that?  Sorry.  I know it's a lot of information all at once!

Connect is easy once you get the hang of it.  Just hang in there.

Comment: Thank you, I will implement your solution, Actually my problem is that I can't connect to another account because when I want to connect then stripe force me to fill up a form including card number and other info. But I don't want to get connected with my card number because it is for testing purpose. I want to know another thing that is it possible to pay money to two account without connect ??? thank u for your cordial response.

Comment: You can connect two Stripe test-accounts.  In your Dashboard [1] you'll have two Client IDs listed: development and production.  If you setup Stripe Connect with your development credentials, you'll get the option to skip that form.

[1] https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/applications/settings